What plays the stability of inductance value over frequency?

I made a measurement of inductance value over frequency and I got the curve as shown.
I see a high drop of inductance value at high frequency (over several kHz)
I don't really understand why the inductance is so sensitive to frequency? What element of inductance (air gap, magnetic material, etc.) plays the role in the stability of the inductance value over the frequency?
Do you have any idea about it?

What is the inductor? Turns, dimensions, core material, etc.?

You have to see the inductor as a non-ideal component. You can make a model of an inductor, as a inductance in series with some series DC resistance. Then you also have coupling between windings, which is modeled as capacitance. It is the capacitance you see in your plot that make the inductance decrease as frequency goes up.
If you look at the impedance vs. frequency of an inductor you will see it increases as frequency goes up. At one point it will resonate and the impedance will go down, because of the parasitic capacitance.
